# xcode UILabel incremental visual update

Tags: xcode, uilabel

Need to make a "score board" like UILabel.  When the view is displayed to the user the UILabel to start at 0 then do an incremental update until it gets to a stored value.  Would like to control how fast the UILabel updates as well.

So for example: 
label starts with 0, then displays 1, next 2, 3, 4, etc... until it gets to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a repeating NSTimer and a counter to achieve this:

```
@interface Whatever: SomeSuperClass {
    int counter;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 /* in seconds */
    target:self
    selector:@selector(updateLabel)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];

- (void)updateLabel
{
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter++];
    if (counter > 20) [timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: @Xaphann In the first part, assign the timer to an instance variable, and stop it when necessary. See update.